# Is there any way to prove a heroku deployment corresponds to a github repo?

Tags: heroku

I want to set an opensource project where users can be sure that the deployed version .heroku.com corresponds with the actual source code in github master branch github.com/

Is there any way to prove a heroku deployment corresponds to a github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Your app can spit out the latest deployed Git SHA if it has the "Dyno Metadata" feature turned on: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

Using that, you can show the latest SHA and compare it against the public repo.

Comment: This could allow the heroku owner to spit a hardcoded SHA that corresponds to a git SHA in master in a code that include malicious modifications. As I mentioned in the question I want users to be absolutely sure that the code deployed corresponds to a github/git branch.

Comment: There's no way for a 3rd party to access the Git SHA deployed, no. This is protected information inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to add to what Jon said, you can do this via the `heroku releases` command. Every release, be it a code deployment, config var is 'tagged' - the command will show you everything that has changed on your app and a deploy will show the short git SHA, you can copy the SHA and then use the git command to search the repo for it.

eg.

assuming `heroku releases` returns

```
v10  Deploy 33f21247        foo@bah.com                2018/09/03 10:01:38 +0100
```

then you could do:

```
git cat-file commit 33f21247
```

which will then output the corresponding match, or a message saying it's not found. Obviously, this assumes your local repo is in sync with GitHub. To check it against GitHub you'd need to open your repo on GitHub like:

https://github.com/heroku/{projectname}/commit/{sha}

which will show the same commit on GitHub.

Comment: This seems like it can only verified by the heroku owner, I want any user to be able to verify that the code deployed corresponds to one in git/github and was not maliciously modified.